# Extracting data from dictionary in panda data-frame

Tags: pandas, dictionary, extract

I am working on cleaning data I scrapped and one of the columns is in for of dictionary in a  list. How can I extract the values of the list in new column. The column name is "age " as shown in the screenshot.

Best regards

I have tried using pandas extract function but did not work.

df['age_claen'] = dff['age'].str.fullmatch('age_message')

[image: screenshot from jupyter notebook]

Comment: see my answer, if that doesn't work, please add your data as text (NOT as image).

Answer (score 0):

```
 df['age_clean'] = [list(e[0].values()) for e in df['age']]
```

The [0] is due to that looks like each value is a dict inside a one-value-list.

Try it.

Regards,

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [34], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df4['age_clean'] = [list(e[0].values()) for e in df4['age']]

Input In [34], in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 df4['age_clean'] = [list(e[0].values()) for e in df4['age']]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: give an AttributeError error

Comment: Look my new answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df.join(df.pop('age').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]))).rename(columns={'age_message' : 'age_clean'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a try in my own python:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDucV.png)

It works with the next code:

```
df['age_clean'] = [list(e[0].values())[0] for e in df['age']]
```

But, it is crucial to ensure that every data of that column has the same structure, if not you are going to receive an Error. Be sure you do not have Nulls or values which are not a dict inside a list.

Regards,

Comment: I tried your data and code and worked for me too.I have trimmed the data set and kept only 3 raws , but with my data  still says: "'str' object has no attribute 'values'".

Comment: You should check all the value types, maybe with a df[column].unique(). Maybe you have some nulls or different type of values. You could manage this problem with an exception. Cleaning DataFrames always is crucial

Answer (score 0):

I used regex andextraction function and managed to resolve the issue as following:

p = r"\s'(\w+)'"
df['newAge']=df.age.str.extract(p,expand=True)

Thank you all and appreciate your help.